# convert JavaScript multidimensional object into flat array

Tags: javascript, object

I have this javascript object format

```
{
  "draw": "",
  "columns": [
    {
      "data": "userid",
      "name": "",
      "searchable": true,
      "search": {
        "value": "",
        "regex": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and what I need to do is convert it into single dimension object like

```
{ 
 "draw" : "",
 "columns[data]": "userid",
 "columns[name]": "",
 "columns[searchable]": "true",
 "columns[searchable][value]": "",
 "columns[searchable][regex]":"true"
}
```

the primary object can be multiple layers deep and contains objects as well as arrays.

any ideas suggestions much appreciated as JS is not my forte.

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `columns[0][searchable][regex]:` instead of `columns[searchable][regex]`?

Comment: isn't it an XY problem? why do you want to do this particular thing? It seems to me like it might be an attempted solution to some other problem you are not telling us about.

Comment: what do you do after getting an object with only one level? and why do you don't have an index for the array? how do you know, that the original data comes from an array?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a recursive function that accepts a property of the original and the path to that object. If the property is not an object, then add the value to the path, if it is, then iterate through its properties and call the recursive function.

```js
var object = {
  "draw": "",
  "columns": [{
    "data": "userid",
    "name": "",
    "searchable": true,
    "search": {
      "value": "",
      "regex": false
    }
  }]
};

console.log(flatten(object));

function flatten(object) {
  var result = {};
  innerFlatten(object, "");
  return result;

  function innerFlatten(object, path) {
    if (typeof object !== "object" || object === null || object instanceof Date) return result[path] = object;
    if (!Object.keys(object).length) return result[path] = object;
    for (var key in object) {
      innerFlatten(object[key], path ? (path + "[" + key + "]") : key);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used some of your logic and this stackoverflow reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896928/flattening-the-nested-object-in-javascript. Created another version of this answer here https://pastebin.com/Xq7RHiTw

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to remove array from `columns` and set to 0 index value

```js
let test = {
  "draw": "",
  "columns": [
    {
      "data": "userid",
      "name": "",
      "searchable": true,
      "search": {
        "value": "",
        "regex": false
      }
    }
   ]
}

test.columns = test.columns[0]

console.log(test)
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants

Comment: @ThumChoonTat Okay I want to delete my answer though my account is guest so I cant